# Cascading ComboBoxes in ExtJS EditorGridPanel

Tags: combobox, extjs, grid

I have a working EditorGrid panel, where two columns have ComboBox editors. Both ComboBoxes are loaded remotely from database (`countryStore` and `cityStore`).

I would like to limit the `cityComboBox` to show only cities in the selected country. I need to reload the `cityStore` with a filter from database (there are too many cities to filter localy). The filter value is the `countryComboBox` value.

There is always a value in countryComboBox, because I add a default = 1 when creating a new record, so this isn't a problem.

I don't know which listener would be appropriate here. I need to catch the moment when I double click on the country cell, before the `countryComboBox` shows up and filter the combo box before it's shown (or display a waiting message while it's retrieving data).

If this is not possible, could I open a popup window by double clicking a cell, choose from a comboBox of filtered cities, "confirm" and enter the value into the cell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally made it work. I created two solutions - for local and remote dropdown searches within the grid. In the end, I decided to use a local search (I can add `country_id` to my `cities` query and filter in ExtJS), but it's possible to make this work for remote searches - if anyone needs that, I can prepare that solution too.

`LOCAL SOLUTION`

I had to filter `cityCombo` using a beforeQuery event, using the id from `countryCombo` in the same row. Here's the code for `cityCombo`:

```
var cityCombo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    triggerAction: 'all',
    mode: 'local',
    lastQuery: '', // to make sure the filter in the store is not cleared the first time the ComboBox trigger is used
    store: cityDropdownStore,
    displayField: 'city',
    valueField: 'city_id',
    listeners: {
        beforeQuery: function(query) { 
            currentRowId = myGrid.getSelectionModel().getSelected().data.country_id;
            this.store.clearFilter();
            this.store.filter( { property: 'country_id', value: currentRowId, exactMatch: true } );
        }
    }
});
```

As you can see, when the `cityCombo` inside the grid is double clicked, I get `country_id` in the current row and filter `cityStore` using that value. This requires `cityStore` to have these fields: `id` , `country_id`, `city`

One problem still remains: when the user changes the `countryCombo`, the city field should change / warn the user that it's not correct for the current country. The solution for this was complicated... as you may know, you cannot get a reference to a comboBox's parentGrid (otherwise you could just call `countryCombo --> parentGrid --> currentRecord --> cityCombo --> change it`).

I tried listening to the rowchange event on the grid itself, but if a user clicked to another row directly after changing `countryCombo`, it changed the wrong row's city.

The solution was somewhat advanced: I had to copy references for current row to cityCombo from the grid's beforeedit event. Here's the grid's listener for this:

```
listeners: {
    beforeedit: function(e) {
        // reference to the currently clicked cell
        var ed = e.grid.getColumnModel().getCellEditor(e.column, e.row);    
        if (ed && ed.field) {
            // copy these references to the current editor (countryCombo in our case)
            Ext.copyTo(ed.field, e, 'grid,record,field,row,column');
        }
    }
},
```

Now our `countryCombo` has all the information neccessary to reset the city when it gets changed. Here's the whole `countryCombo` code:

```
var countryCombo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    id: 'skupina_combo',
    typeAhead: true,
    triggerAction: 'all',
    lazyRender: true,
    mode: 'local',
    store: countryDropdownStore,
    displayField: 'country',
    valueField: 'country_id',
    listeners: {
        change: function(t, n, o) {    // t is the reference to the combo
            // I have t.record available only because I copied it in the beforeEdit event from grid
            t.record.set('city_id', '0');
        }

    }
});
```

Cell renderers didn't have a problem with me filtering their store, so I only needed one store for both rendering and comboBox editing (cityStore).

The remote solution required me to create two stores for cities - `cityRendererStore` and `cityDropdownStore`, which queried the database each time instead of using filters. That approach is neccessary if you have too many cities to filter locally. I should mention I'm not really using cities and countries in my application, I just created this example to simplify things.

I'm really happy about the end result - it gives all the benefits of a grid together with conditional dropdowns usually available only in forms.

Answer (score 1):

I can see a couple options here.  You could catch the store's `update` event (when the underlying record is updated or marked dirty) or catch the countryComboBox's `select` event.  Both of those will provide you with the id value of the selected country, which you can then add to your cityComboBox's `baseParams` for remote filtering.

Comment: I tried the first suggestion already (store's `update` event), but it's not working - imagine I want to edit an existing record's City - I double click the city dropdown, there was no store change yet. The `select` on cityComboBox fires only when you select a value in the dropdown - I need it to be filtered before I select anything. The `select` on countryComboBox is not fired when editing an existing record's City only (same as `update store` problem).

Comment: But you already know what the city combo should default to, since you're defaulting `country = 1` right?  A code sample in your question showing your grid configuration and event handlers would be helpful :)

Comment: Well, my code wouldn't do much good, because everything is working as far as dynamic dropdowns in editable grid go. I need the new code. Regarding your comment: yes, I always have country = 1 (or country = existing value in record), but my problem is how to filter the `cityCombobBox` on the current row's `countryComboBox` field (which I have).

Comment: Well I guess I'm at a loss then.  Perhaps you could catch the combo's `beforeQuery` event and read the record then for the param to filter on.

Comment: I'll try `beforeQuery` - I know this is a complex situation, thank you for your suggestions. If I manage to make it work, I'll share the solution here.