# setting the store of a combobox in EditableGrid in ExtJs based on another combo

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

i am using **ext designer**. (ext version 3.x)
i have  a combo in a form with autoref 'worker_type'

then there is an editable grid, to add employees

the grid has a employee selection combo as illustrated in the image

i want change the store of this combo based on the 'worker_type' selection.
my goal here is to list employees of a certain worker type only.

but i am unable to access the editable grid combo box in code anyway.

any assistance will be highly appreciated.

thanks

[image: employee selection combo]

Comment: this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980796/cascading-comboboxes-in-extjs-editorgridpanel

Answer (score 0):

Put a select listener to your first combo, and on selecting a value, load the data store of the second combo. Somewhat this way:

```
var firstCombo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    mode : 'local',
    store : firstStore,
    ......
    listeners : {
        scope : this,
        select : function(combo){
            // Here load the "secondStore" with selected combo value
            // Combo value is combo.getValue()
        }
    }

});


var secondCombo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    mode : 'local',
    store : secondStore,
    ......
});
```

Comment: Ext-designer will ultimately provide you a set of codes. If you want some custom functionality, you have to go inside code. Designer will only create the interface, not any complex functionality.

Comment: ext desginer creates two sets of code files. ui.js and .js, ui files are regenerated on any minor change, and thats where this code belongs :(, so u see my problem, the .js files cannot create combo boxes and insert to the editable grid. i cant set listeners to the combos in the generated files for this reason.